# Access HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in a Thymeleaf dialect processor

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a Thymeleaf dialect processor which performs a ServletDispatcher.include. I have extended the AbstractElementTagProcessor and overridden the doProcess method. The relevant code fragment is:

```
@Override
protected void doProcess(final ITemplateContext context, final IProcessableElementTag tag, final IElementTagStructureHandler structureHandler) {
    ServletContext servletContext = null; // TODO: get servlet context
    HttpServletRequest request = null; // TODO: get request
    HttpServletResponse response = null; // TODO: get response

    // Retrieve dispatcher to component JSP view
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/something");

    // Create wrapper (acts as response, but stores output in a CharArrayWriter)
    CharResponseWrapper wrapper = new CharResponseWrapper(response);

    // Run the include
    dispatcher.include(request, wrapper);

    String result = wrapper.toString();

    // Create a model with the returned string
    final IModelFactory modelFactory = context.getModelFactory();
    final IModel model = modelFactory.parse(context.getTemplateData(), result);

    // Instruct the engine to replace this entire element with the specified model
    structureHandler.replaceWith(model, false);
```

I wrote similar code in the past in the form of a custom JSP tag. Problem is: I don't know how to access the ServletContext, HttpServletRequest and the HttpServletResponse!
Can this be done at all, or should I just accept that Thymeleaf is too good at hiding the HTTP context?

Answer (score 7):

You can access request (by using `#request` object that gives you the direct access to `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` object) parameters and session (with `#session` object that gives you direct access to the `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` object) attributes directly in Thymeleaf views:

```
${#request.getAttribute('foo')}
${#request.getParameter('foo')}
${#request.getContextPath()}
${#request.getRequestName()}

<p th:if="${#request.getParameter('yourParameter') != null
      th:text="${#request.getParameter('yourParameter')}"}">Request Param</p>

${#session.getAttribute('foo')}
${#session.id}
${#session.lastAccessedTime}

<p th:if="${session != null}"> th:text="${session.yourAttribute}"</p>
```

Read more [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-basic-objects).

Comment: Thanks, DimaSan. I am aware of this, but I would like to abstract all this away from people who write the views. They should just be able to use my  dialect, like this: <my:tag/>

Comment: I see, then maybe this article will be useful for you: [Extending Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/extendingthymeleaf.pdf). Take a look on chapter **3.4. An element processor for our headlines**.

Comment: Thank you. After reading that article I still don't see how to access the current request, servlet context and/or response from within the processor. I guess it simply isn't possible. I will look for an alternative solution.

Comment: Probably you are right. But if you find any solution please post it here as it will be really useful.

Comment: You should be able to get the request object from the IExpressionContext that you can get from the ITemplateContext that is passed to your processor.

Comment: This is no longer allowed [as of Thymeleaf 3.1](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf31whatsnew.html). See related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75490693.

Answer (score 2):

I found myself with a very similar requirement of accessing the `request` from an implementation of `IExpressionObjectFactory`.

The way i solved it (following @Sebastian Marsching advise in a previous comment) is by accessing the objects registered in `IExpressionContext` that are available from the view in the context of template evaluation (all those objects described in [Appendix A](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-a-expression-basic-objects) and [Appendix B](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-b-expression-utility-objects) of thymeleaf documentation), so you have access to request, response, servletContext and many other utility objects.

Speaking in code:

```
IExpressionObjects expressionObjects = context.getExpressionObjects();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)expressionObjects.getObject("request");
```

There is also an `expressionObjects.getObjectNames()` method you can call to get a `Set<String>` with the names of all registered objects, which in my case gives the following list:

```
[i18nutils, ctx, root, vars, object, locale, request, response, session,
servletContext, conversions, uris, calendars, dates, bools, numbers, objects,
strings, arrays, lists, sets, maps, aggregates, messages, ids, execInfo,
httpServletRequest, httpSession, fields, themes, mvc, requestdatavalues]
```