# Check if Thymeleaf template url contains string

Tags: spring, templates, thymeleaf

How can I check if this URL 'http://localhost:8080/employees/subordinates/1' contains the string 'subordinates'? I'm trying to make the presence of an anchor conditional upon the URL containing the phrase. This is what I've been hoping to achieve.

```
<div th:if="${#strings.contains(#httpServletRequest.requestURI, 'subordinates')}">
    <a href="/employees/list">employee directory</a>
</div>
```

Comment: [I'm unable to reproduce your behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqZBH.png).  When I have a controller with `/subordinates`, I correctly see the link `employee directory`.  Are you sure this is where the error is happening?

Comment: As soon as I include my code in a template I get a white label error page with the following message 'Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'requestURI' cannot be found on null'. Is the httpServletRequest object available to the template by default, or must it be explicitly provisioned?

Comment: I ask because, when I replace #httpServletRequest with #request, I get this error: 'The 'request','session','servletContext' and 'response' expression utility objects are no longer available by default for template expressions and their use is not recommended. In cases where they are really needed, they should be manually added as context variables.'

Comment: When I autowire the HttpServletRequest into the controller and add it as a model attribute I get a 'org.springframework.expression.EvaluationException: Accessing member 'requestURI' is forbidden for type...' error

Comment: The only work around I can find is to add the URI to the model and reference that in the template: model.addAttribute("URI", request.getRequestURI()); and <div th:if="${#strings.contains(URI, 'subordinates')}">.

Comment: I've also tried to capture the URI in a th:with="", but this seems not to work either. Has access to the URI etc been withdrawn for security reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the workaround you mention in the comments is the way to do it.

The `#request`, `#response`, `#session`, and `#servletContext` expression utility objects are no longer available in Thymeleaf 3.1. According to this [issue](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/886):

> The #request, #response, #session and #servletContext expression utility objects should be removed from the Standard Dialect, both for security reasons (in order to avoid direct access to potentially unsafe properties such as request parameters) and also due to the fact that these are currently bound to the javax.* Servlet API, and generalizing the web interfaces in the Thymeleaf core in order to support jakarta.* and other web technologies would not be compatible with these specific objects still being available.

The article [Thymeleaf 3.1: What’s new and how to migrate](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf31whatsnew.html) recommends adding to your model, at the controller level, the specific pieces of information your templates need from these objects. For example, you can add the following to your controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("requestURI")
public String requestURI(final HttpServletRequest request) {
   return request.getRequestURI();
}
```

And use the attribute in your template this way:

```
<div th:if="${#strings.contains(${requestURI}, 'subordinates')}">
    <a href="/employees/list">employee directory</a>
</div>
```